# A datagram of 2020 bytes is being sent and the MTU is 1020 bytes. The headers have 20 bytes. How many fragments are created, and what is the offset?

Tags: networking, udp

> A datagram with a total of 2020 bytes is being sent. The MTU is 1020 bytes. Assume the headers have 20 bytes.
>
> a) How many fragments are created and what are their sizes?
>
> b) What is the offset and the fragmentation flag of each datagram?

a) Two datagrams with 1020 bytes each. The solutions confirm this but don't explain. I think it's because the first one has 1000 bytes and the header and the other one has the remaining 1020 bytes, which make a total of 2040 bytes. Is this correct?

b) The fragmentation flag of the first one is 1 and the 2nd one is 0. I don't know about the offsets. The offset on the 1st packet is 0 and the solutions say the offset on the second one is 125. I don't understand why. The other answer is 0 and 1000. This one makes a lot more sense to me, but it's not the right one according to the solutions.

Help?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question.

Comment: a) yes b) fragmentation offset field is the offset divided by 8, i.e. 1000/8 = 125. See https://ipwithease.com/fragmentation-offset/

Comment: @pigeonburger: homework questions are not off-topic by themselves. The problem is only if users simply ask others to solve the question w/o doing anything by their own. In this case the OP is trying to solve the question, showing this  and asking for very specific help in understanding the solutions.